# Save progress or actions of user in django?

Tags: django

I have a series of tasks which need to be completed by users when they signup. I need to keep track of this. For now am checking if data exists in more than 5 tables (like address, education etc.). I think this is not a good way of doing this. Whenever a user logins, I need to check if they have finished all the basic tasks and then allow them to do other things.

On doing research, I have few options:

- Option1: Create a new model and store all progress on each row
  and then fetch all the rows to check if required is completed.
- Option2: Create a new model and store the finished actions in a array, for instance:

```
Class Actions:
      owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      actions = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=128))
```

And with these, I can append all the finished tasks one by one, like `{emailverification,personal_details,education_details}` etc.

And then use the above to work on the conditions.

I think the second option is more effective, as it just fetches on row from the table instead of fetching multiple rows.

Or please suggest any new option to track this.

Comment: just add some boolean fields to the Model like `address_maintained`, `edcuation_maintained` etc.

Comment: What if in near future i need to add an extra step ? This will lead to alter whole table right ?

Comment: then you just add another field to the model

Comment: ya, for example - if i have more than ten thousand records and when i add a new field wont it make any disturbance ! And meanwhile i have multiple roles like students, university ! And each has seperate actions to be done when they register ! How to handle this when there are multiple user roles ? As for university there wont be any  ```edcuation_maintained```

Answer (score 0):

add json field in model and dump user's actions in it.
plus use "from django_extensions.db.fields.json import  JSONField" instead of "models.JSONField" because it doesn't go well with SQL

Answer (score 0):

1. `Action` - the model name should be singular
2. I would use a `BooleanField` in User model, so you don't have to do other selects, if he has already finished all the steps and you can do just:

```py
if not request.user.finished_all_steps:
  # select from Action and let him finish it
  pass
```

and then it's up to you, if you wanna use Action.actions as a `JSONField`, or you make a row per every action

Comment: How to handle this with multiple roles of users ! Like students and university ? both have different steps !

Comment: easy, you can save whatever in the JSONField. So when he finishes one step, you check by the role which steps remain, and if none, you set the finished_all_steps to true

Comment: If its json, then it can be handled ! How to handle when we use Boolean

Comment: I would actually save every step as an extra row in Action, instead of the JSONField, so you can also save a datetime of when he finished the step. Who knows when you'll need it ;) the bool will be in User model + you make a model Action with user fk, name (of the step) and datetime

Comment: What if i dont need the time ?

Comment: what if you do and you wont have it :D I mean, it's up to you, but one day you might decide "hmm, if a user doesnt finish all his steps and is 6 months inactive, I'm gonna delete his account"
or you might wanna send him an email notification in two weeks, that he forgot to finish 2 steps, whatever

Comment: or two weeks without emailverification - then you might wanna delete the account, because it might be a troll using someone elses email address, thus blocking him from real registration

Comment: Got it, one role will easily have  7 actions and with this rate we would reach more than million rows in few months ! Will that be expensive to use this - as we need fetch all the rows !

Comment: fk field has index, so shouldnt be a problem... but you might also delete the rows of a user, when he finishes all steps, or move it to a backup table (model), if you think you might need it as a log one day

Comment: @sixovov947: or you might consider using cache (memcached/redis) for the Action, instead of a model, it depends how long you expect them to finish all the steps

Comment: I need to keep the log untill the end of our application :D ! As i need to check these everytime when user perform somethings ! So i need to persist the data till the end

Comment: for that you will have the bool in User model, but the Action model is more or less for temporary data, or do I get it wrong?

Comment: Action in the sense, am storing data's in separate tables like education, etc ! So need keep track if the student has finished the education or not ! Likewise for 7 tables